# Ajax callback not returning options for checkboxes

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm triggering an ajax callback on change event of a dropdown, this method returns additional form elements like text fields, number and checkboxes, but for checkboxes the options are not appearing at all.

```
---------
Container for additional elements

  $form['dynamic_field_container'] = [
                '#type' => 'container',  
                '#attributes' => ['id' => 'dynamic-field-wrapper'],
              ];

----------

   public function ProjectOptions($data, $ProjectOptions)
    {
        return [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#options' => $data,
            '#title' => t('Options Name'),
            '#required' => TRUE,
            '#default_value' => $ProjectOptions,
     
            '#ajax' => [
              'callback' => [$this,'dynamicFieldCallback'],
              'wrapper' => 'dynamic-field-wrapper',
              'event' => 'change',
              'progress' => [
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => t('Loading...'),
              ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function dynamicFieldCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
            $form['dynamic_field_container']['number_field'] = [
                    '#type' => 'number',
                    '#title' => t('Number field titile'),
                    '#description' => t('This field changes based on dropdown selection.'),
                    '#required' => TRUE,
                    '#value' =>'555'
                  ];
            $options = [
                        'option1' => 'Option 1',
                        'option2' => 'Option 2',
                        'option3' => 'Option 3',
                ];
            $form['dynamic_field_container']['dynamic_field_checkbox' ] = [
                    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
                    '#title' => t('Titile of the Check box field'),
                    '#description' => t('This field changes based on dropdown selection.'),
                    '#required' => TRUE,
                    '#options' => $options,
                    '#value' => true
                ];
        return $form['dynamic_field_container'];
    }
```

[image: In the output, only the title of checkboxes are visible]

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/314435/dynamicaly-add-ajax-form-item-and-add-event-on-checkbox

Comment: Thanks! By calling the processCheckboxes, processAjaxForm i was able to render the options but I'm still unable to set either the '#value' or '#default_value' to the checkboxes element.